# How to declare an array of structs as storage variables?

Tags: solidity

I do not want to use .push and would like to define a static, const array of struct on top.

```
  struct Info{
    address a;          
    uint256 b;       
    uint256 c;  
    uint256 d; 
}

Info[] public infoArrary = [
{0xabcd,1,2,3},
{0xabcd,1,2,3},
];
```

It gives me compilation errors. I am a C guy, so please advise.

Comment: To begin with, you'd need to encapsulate each entry with `Info(...)`.

Comment: For example, `Info({0xabcd,1,2,3})`.

Comment: Second, you'll need to declare well ahead the total number of elements in this array. Unlike C, in Solidity, omitting that number from inside the `[]` implies that the array is dynamic (i.e., can add and remove elements). And if it's dynamic, then you can add and remove elements to it only inside functions, meaning the you cannot initialize it at declaration.

Comment: Third, for your on "well being", you'd better use field names, in case you ever choose to rearrange or extend this structure. For example: `Info({a: address(0xabcd), b: 1, c: 2, d: 3})`.

Comment: Thank you @goodvibration, I think I am almost there - instead of address a in the struct, it is actually IERC20 a, which is an interface called IERC20 (another contract). a: address(0xabc) gives me :   TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address payable to contract IERC20 requested. thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, replace `address` with `IERC20` (which as a C programmer, should be the first thing that comes to your mind).

Comment: @goodvibration I did. and it didnt work.  Copying of type struct X.Info memory[2] memory to storage not yet supported.

Comment: That's a misleading comment though, because the compilation error you got before you've applied that - was different. So it actually did work, it just left you with yet another problem (one which I can't help you with, because as you may understand, it is currently not supported by the language).

Comment: so essentially declaring array of structs is not possible with solidity. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Declaring an array of structs is very well possible with solidity. You just need to initialize it in a function.

Answer (score 5):

Initializing a storage array of structures upon declaration is currently not supported.

You need to initialize the array in the constructor (or in any other function if you wish).

You have two options:

1. A static array - if you do not intend to add or remove elements during execution:

```
Info[2] public infoArrary;
...
constructor() public {
    infoArrary2[0] = Info({a: 0xSomeAddress1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3});
    infoArrary2[1] = Info({a: 0xSomeAddress2, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4});
}
```

2. A dynamic array - if you do intend to add or remove elements during execution:

```
Info[] public infoArrary;
...
constructor() public {
    infoArrary.push(Info({a: 0xSomeAddress1, b: 1, c: 2, d: 3}));
    infoArrary.push(Info({a: 0xSomeAddress2, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}));
}
```

Comment: thank you. why is solidity like this? such garbage.

Comment: @user2584960: It's a relative new language. Work on the compiler (solc) is ongoing, and far from being what you just called it.

Comment: lol you are correct. i agree. btw I really appreciate your help. off topic - I just realized you cannot iterate mapping. are you serious....